# error: control may reach end of non-void function

Tags: c, function

This error appeared to me when i was trying to compile a c file which contains a declaration of a linear search function

```
bool search(int value, int values[], int n)
{
// TODO: implement a searching algorithm
  for(int d = 0;d<n;d++){
    if(n<0){
     return false;
    } 
    else if(values[d]==value){
      return true;
    }
    else{
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

What is wrong with my code? Please help.

Comment: See my answer, they're some other problems in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some problems with the code:

1. The method have a path that don't return anything, as commented, when parameter `n = negative number or 0`
2. The for-loop don't do anything, will only execute one time and exit for one of the conditions. It would only work correctly when the first element is the element searched, in any other case only check the first element and return (without correct info of present or not). Test with array `int values[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };` and search `3`, your code would not found this value.

If you're searching for a specific value the code is:

```
bool search(int value, int values[], int n) {
    for (int d = 0; d < n; d++) {
        if (values[d] == value) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: And what should i do if i have an else if condition do another loop ?

Comment: the `if-else` would execute one of the two branch always and your code return in the two branch, in this case you would always return the function in the first execution of the loop (some compiler warn about this, almost sure that clang does).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the argument n passed to the function is `n <= 0`. The loop never executes and the function finishes without returning any value.

To fix it put the `if(n <= 0)` statement before the `for` loop.

Comment: @user297904 Yes. Fixed.

Comment: @user297904 it needs to be before the loop though, that's the important part. It's kinda redundant to check that after you've entered the loop.

Comment: This only don't work. See my answer. The `for-loop` in any case would only execute one time (incorrectly).

Comment: Do you understand if he puts the if statement before the loop that it will then exit the function if n is <= 0.

Comment: Yes and would fix that problem (that it's not the only problem)

Answer (score 0):

If the 'for' loop doesn't get to do any iterations you won't be able to return anything from the function. Maybe add an edge case like

```
if(n <=0 )
    return false;
```

before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

`d` is incremented in the `for` loop until it equals the value of `n`.  At that point, the code beyond the `for` loop is executed.

Being that there are no instructions beyond the `for` loop, the function returns to the caller.  The `error` occurs due to there being no (boolean) value returned from the function in this case.

The error can be avoided by following Rule #1 of the [Mahonri List Of Rules For Writing Maintainable C Code](http://www.mahonri.info/doc/MahonriListOfRulesForWritingMaintainableCCode.html).  Example:

```
bool search(int value, int values[], int n)
   {
   bool rCode=false;

   // TODO: implement a searching algorithm
   for(int d = 0;d<n;d++)
      {
      if(n<0)
        {
        goto CLEANUP;
        } 
     else if(values[d]==value)
        {
        rCode=true;
        goto CLEANUP;
        }
     else
        {
        goto CLEANUP;
        }
     } 

CLEANUP:

   return(rCode);
   }
```